# How can I make an intentionally slow LINQ to SQL query?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I need to make a slow LINQ to SQL query for testing purposes. Just want to see how our system reacts when there's a long-running query.

I have a few tables with up to 50,000 rows but my queries are taking less than a second. How can I make a query that runs for a long time?

Comment: Did you try to add many conditions? like

var somelist = (from m in db.Table where m.column1 != "sometext1" && m.column2 != "sometext2" and so on...???

Also write many such queries and try to use joins to merge multiple conditions. I think it will be sufficient for your need.

Comment: Add a couple layers of sub quires.  The growth will be exponential.

Comment: Create a stored procedure returning records with `WAITFOR`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, I forgot that the actual database access only happens when ToList() is called. I had been thinking that my query was still still super-fast because I was only checking the line that sets up the query.

I was able to sufficiently slow down my query but simply duplicating the joins and where clauses, like this except 5 times longer:

```
var query =
                from aa in db.MyTable
                from aa1 in db.MyTable
                from aa2 in db.MyTable
                from aa3 in db.MyTable
                join bb in db.OtherTable on aa.PartNumber equals bb.PartNumber
                join bb1 in db.OtherTable on aa1.PartNumber equals bb1.PartNumber
                join bb2 in db.OtherTable on aa2.PartNumber equals bb2.PartNumber
                join bb3 in db.OtherTable on aa3.PartNumber equals bb3.PartNumber
                where
                    aa.Column == "something" &&
                    aa1.Column == "something" &&
                    aa2.Column == "something" &&
                    aa3.Column == "something" &&
                select new
                {
                    PropertyOne = pr.ColumnOne,
                    PropertyTwo = oo.ColumnTwo,
                };

var list = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use joins and order by in your query. The joins and order by operations lag out SQL server. So your query result time will be higher.